# Sign of a SOAPMessage via SecurityTokenReference and Thumprint identificator with Apache CXF

Tags: soap, cxf, ws-security

Does someone could give an implementation idea for sighning of a SOAPMessage using Apache CFX library (like WSSecSignature  and Crypto classes and related data structure) in order to have implemented at the end something like :

```
<oas:Security> 
    <oas:Signature> 
         <xd:SignedInfo> 
              <xd:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/> 
              <xd:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/> 
              <xd:Reference URI="#[BodyID]"> 
                  <xd:Transforms> 
                       <xd:Transform Algorithm="[TransformAlgorithm]"/> 
                  </xd:Transforms>
                  <xd:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>                                               
                  <xd:DigestValue>[DigestValue]</xd:DigestValue> 
             </xd:Reference> 
             <xd:Reference URI="#[ControlID]"> 
                  <xd:Transforms>
                       <xd:Transform Algorithm="[TransformAlgorithm]"/> 
                  </xd:Transforms> 
                  <xd:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/> 
                  <xd:DigestValue>[DigestValue]</xd:DigestValue> 
             </xd:Reference> 
         </xd:SignedInfo> 
         <xd:SignatureValue>[SignatureValue]</xd:SignatureValue>
         <xd:KeyInfo> 
             <oas:SecurityTokenReference> 
                  <oas:KeyIdentifier ValueType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbPrintSHA1">[Thumbprint] 
                  </oas:KeyIdentifier> 
              </oas:SecurityTokenReference> 
         </xd:KeyInfo> 
     </oas:Signature> 
  </oas:Security>
```

I there a good resource, from where I can find the way of implementing of sighing of a SOAPMessage ?

Thanks in advance guys, 
SImeon